# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'implicitly_wait'

Tags: linux, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework, pageobjects

I've setup robot-framework on `linux` along with python and selenium.
When i execute sample.robot file (to launch a browser), it works fine. But encountering a problem, when it calls selenium `api`.

As soon as `validate_google_page` in test.robot is called, it throws **error**.
Am i missing any paths here ?

sample.robot : works fine

> test.robot : encounters error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'implicitly_wait'

which python
`/usr/bin/python`

```
export $PYTHONPATH
-bash: export: `/usr/bin/python': not a valid identifier

echo $PATH
/home/user_name/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

pip show robotframework

    Name: robotframework
    Version: 3.0.2
    Summary: Generic automation framework for acceptance testing and robotic process automation (RPA)
    Home-page: http://robotframework.org
    Author: Pekka Klärck
    Author-email: peke@eliga.fi
    License: Apache License 2.0
    Location: /home/user_name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    Requires: 

uname -a
Linux ip-10-10-10-10 4.15.0-1032-aws #34-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 17 15:18:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Installed

    robotframework==3.0.2
    robotframework-debuglibrary==1.1.4
    robotframework-pageobjects==1.3.3
    robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0


sample.robot

    *** Settings ***
    Library    Selenium2Library

    Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers
    Test Setup  Open Chrome

    *** Keywords ***

    Open Chrome
        ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
        Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}


    *** Test Cases ***
    Go to google
        Go To    https://google.com

test.robot

    *** Settings ***
    Library    Selenium2Library
    Library    ../some_path/directory/test.py

    Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers
    Test Setup  Open Chrome

    *** Keywords ***

    Open Chrome
        ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
        Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}


    *** Test Cases ***
    Go to google
        Go To    https://google.com
        validate_google_page

test.py

    from robotpageobjects import Page, robot_alias
    import time
    from time import sleep

    class Test(Page):
        selectors = {
            "search username": "id=userName",
            "search password": "id=password"
            }

    def validate_google_page(self):
            self.wait_until_element_is_visible("search username")
            return self
```

> Error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'implicitly_wait'
>   Expected : Should run smoothly.

Comment: @here : can anyone please help me ? what could be the issue ?

Comment: Please explain what's your end goal for these python keywords. The current code has too many errors - your are creating a webdriver session through Selenium2Library, but in the py you don't connect to it or get a reference, you just start calling methods as it is accessible. The `wait_until_element_is_visible()` takes as an argument a locator or webelement - but you're passing a string; presumably you wanted to pass the value in the dict - but you don't do that. P.S. there's no such thing as "@here" in SO - you don't expect all site users to be notified and look at your question, do you ;)

Comment: I'm just trying to run a python selenium webdriver code, unfortunately getting this error. Dunno, what could be the cause here. And I'm sorry for mentioning @here 

Comment: I haven't ever looked at the code of the `robotpageobjects` lib, but my bet is it either initializes a webdriver itself, or expects one to be passed to it. You are doing neither - so `wait_until_element_is_visible()` doesn't have anything to work with, and fails somewhere downstream. I would suggest to try accomplishing your goal in pure Robot Framework & SeleniumLibrary code, and fall back to python only for more complicated logic and constructs - that'll be much easier.

Comment: Sure, Thank you.